# In the 'mssql', there is only value of y and n. It can be outputed opposite value by using 'ng-options'?

Tags: angularjs

```
enter code here             <tr ng-repeat="item in selectResult track by $index | orderBy : 'itemID'">
                                <td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.siteCode"></td>
                                <td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.itemID"></td>
                                <td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.itemName"></td>
                                <td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.itemAmt"></td>
                                <td><select ng-options="kitchenPRT_Y for kitchenPRT_Y in item.kitchenPRT_Y" ng-model="item.kitchenPRT_Y"/></td>
                            </tr>
```

[mssql link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogIDE.jpg)

[Screen Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdR1w.jpg)

In the 'mssql', there is only value of y and n. It can be outputed opposite value by using 'ng-options'?

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here             <tr ng-repeat="item in selectResult track by $index | orderBy : 'itemID'">
                                <td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.siteCode"></td>
                                <td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.itemID"></td>
                                <td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.itemName"></td>
                                <td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.itemAmt"></td>
                                <%-- <td><select ng-options="kitchenPRT_Y for kitchenPRT_Y in item.kitchenPRT_Y" ng-model="item.kitchenPRT_Y"/></td> --%>
                                <td><select ng-model="item.kitchenPRT_Y">
                                        <option>Y</option>
                                        <option>N</option>
                                    </select>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

I had solve